# URL Rewrite срабатывает как редирект

Tags: url, redirect, iis, rewrite

Есть устройство, светодиодное табло, которое запрашивает файл `001.htm`, в котором текстом (без `html`) передаются данные для отображения. Я написал сайт на `web forms`, в котором `aspx` страница возвращает данные в требуемом формате. Для того, чтобы старый адрес продолжал работать, я сделал элементарное правило в `rewrite url`, в котором `001.htm` заменяется на `tablo-data.aspx`. В браузере все работает нормально, запросив `001.htm` получаем нужные данные, только адрес в строке браузера меняется на подставленный. И если смотреть запросы, то видно, что сервер на запрос `GET 001.htm` возвращает код `302` и новый адрес, по которому выполняется новый запрос и возвращаются данные. Но табло не умеет ходить по редиректам. Нужно, чтобы данные возвращались сразу.
В описании `url rewrite` говорится, что `rewrite` должно обрабатываться внутри сервера и не менять адрес в браузере. Почему же у меня это не работает?
Вот правило из `web.config`, созданное визардом.

```
<rewrite>
  <rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="001.htm">
      <add key="001.htm" value="tablo-data.aspx" />
    </rewriteMap>
  </rewriteMaps>
  <rules>
    <rule name="htm to aspx" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="001.htm" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="tablo-data.aspx" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Да, наверно это имеет значение: на сайте используется авторизация и конечный URL выглядит как-то так http://xxxxx.ru/tablo_new/(S(3qhyvkxmp3ottea0hrfyjn2y))/tablo-data.aspx

Comment: Да, похоже дело в авторизации. Пришлось сделать еще один маленький сайт без авторизации, который только возвращает данные. Там rewrite работает. Но если есть решение как это сделать не разбивая сайт на два, буду рад услышать.

Answer (score 0):

Редирект у вас срабатывает потому что на редиректах построена авторизация.

Чтобы открыть доступ к конкретной странице без авторизации - надо разрешить анонимный доступ к ней:

```
<location path="tablo-data.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Если не поможет - попробуйте еще для 001.htm тоже анонимный доступ разрешить.

Comment: Ничего не изменилось. Страница и раньше открывалась без авторизации, но через редирект. Единственное решение, которое я нашел, это поместить нужные страницы в отдельную папку и объявить ее отдельным приложением в IIS, что я, в сущности, и сделал. Причина в том, что настройки аутентификации действуют для всего приложения и их нельзя отключить для отдельного элемента.